# A JButton To Determine The Action To Be Performed Based On A JComboBox Choice

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I developed a simple JFrame that is composed of a panel containing a label, a combo box and a button. All I want is to redirect the user to different panels based on his choice from the combo box. I seem to have an error when making the button check the chosen item. Here's what I've done so far...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test 
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        // The Frame Design Part...
        final JFrame ApplicationFrame=new JFrame("Bounceable Ball Game");
        ApplicationFrame.setVisible(true);
        ApplicationFrame.setSize(600,600);
        ApplicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ApplicationFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JMenuBar ApplicationMenuBar=new JMenuBar();
        JMenu File=new JMenu("File");
        JMenu Edit=new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu Play=new JMenu("Play");
        ApplicationMenuBar.add(File);
        JMenuItem Exit=new JMenuItem("Exit");
        File.add(Exit);
        ApplicationMenuBar.add(Edit);
        ApplicationMenuBar.add(Play);
        ApplicationFrame.setJMenuBar(ApplicationMenuBar);
        JPanel ApplicationPanel =new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints DesignConstraints=new GridBagConstraints();
        DesignConstraints.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        DesignConstraints.gridx=0;
        DesignConstraints.gridy=1;
        JLabel GameChoiceLabel=new JLabel("Please Select The Game That You Want To Play...");
        ApplicationPanel.add(GameChoiceLabel,DesignConstraints);
        DesignConstraints.gridx=0;
        DesignConstraints.gridy=2;
        ApplicationPanel.add(GameChoiceComboBox,DesignConstraints);
        DesignConstraints.gridx=0;
        DesignConstraints.gridy=3;
        JButton GameChoiceButton=new JButton("Play Game");  
        GameChoiceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                if(selected.toString().equals("TennisBall"))
                {
                    ApplicationMenuBar.add(File);
                    JMenuItem Exit=new JMenuItem("Exit");
                    File.add(Exit);
                    ApplicationMenuBar.add(Edit);
                    ApplicationMenuBar.add(Play);
                    ApplicationFrame.setJMenuBar(ApplicationMenuBar);
                    JPanel ApplicationPanel1 =new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                    ApplicationFrame.setContentPane(ApplicationPanel1);
                }
            }
        });
        ApplicationPanel.add(GameChoiceButton,DesignConstraints);
        ApplicationFrame.setContentPane(ApplicationPanel);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide the error please? I think I might know the problem

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox @JosefE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the ActionListener to a JButton:

```
GameChoiceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
```

But then you're trying to cast the source of the ActionEvent (which will always be that JButton) to a JComboBox (which it will never be):

```
JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
```

Just refer to the JComboBox directly instead of trying to finagle it out of the getSource() function. You'll either have to pass the JComboBox into the ActionListener, or call a method in the outer class that accesses the JComboBox, or make the JComboBox final.

Comment: I made the JComboBox final but it generated the same error. How do I pass the JComboBox into the ActionListener?

Comment: Don't get the JComboBox from the source. The JComboBox will never be the source. Just refer to it directly using the variable name. You don't need to bother with the getSource() method, since the source will always be the JButton.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

This is in the action when the GameChoiceButton is clicked. But then you get the source (which is the button) and try to cast it to a JComboBox.

To make your code work, make these changes:

```
final JComboBox GameChoiceComboBox=new JComboBox();  //MAKE THIS FINAL
...

GameChoiceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        //USE THE COMBO BOX DIRECTLY and getSelectedItem()
        if(GameChoiceComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("TennisBall"))  

        {
            JMenuBar ApplicationMenuBar=new JMenuBar();
            JMenu File=new JMenu("File");
            JMenu Edit=new JMenu("Edit");
```